# How do I connect this cables to my surface socket australia

Tags: electrical, wiring

[image][image]

I know red go together and black cables go together.
But what do I do with yellow and there is copper out of one black red pair what is that where do I connect that, and this is going to my surface socket for dowlight..

Your suggestion is appropriated. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the yellow wire have green stripes?

Comment: Are you sure your electrical codes don't require you to make those splices inside junction boxes? Is one of the cables going to a switch?

Comment: No yellow wire is full yellow.. And it is going to common in the switch.. If that helps

Answer (score 1):

If you know how the old light was hooked up, connect it in the same way, and ensure that all cables are suitably restrained (e.g. pinclips near the socket, or cable ties).

If you don't know, then this is almost certainly electrician time. It's likely that what's been done is no longer common practice, and possibly no longer legal. It's unclear simply from wire colours how it's hooked up; one would need to not just trace out how it is wired, but understand *why*.